# How can I make sure DynamoDB putItem was successful

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using amazon sdk v2 and using aws factory for dynamoDB and I have a simple putItem operation but I have no idea how I can make sure putItem was successful or not because putItem returns a Model which doesnt contain any information about status of operation. Any idea?
Here is my code

```
class DynamoLogger{
protected $client;
protected $tableName;

public function __construct(ServiceBuilder $builder, $tableName)
{
    $this->client = $builder->get('dynamodb');
    $this->tableName = $tableName;
}

public function log(Request $request)
{
    $model = $this->client->putItem(array(
        'TableName' => $this->tableName,
        'Item' => array(
            'cc_id' => array(
                'S' => $request->get('cc_id')
            ),
            'date' => array(
                'S' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8)
            ),
            'tt_id' => array(
                'N' => $request->get('tt_id')
            ),
            'action_name' => array(
                'S' => $request->get('name')
            ),
            'action_value' => array(
                'S' => $request->get('value')
            ),
            'gg_nn' => array(
                'S' => $request->get('gg_nn')
            ),
            'ffr_id' => array(
                'N' => $request->get('ffr_id')
            )
        ),
        'ReturnValues' => 'ALL_OLD'
    ));
    return $model;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the AWS SDK for PHP 2.x, you should assume that any operation that returns without throwing an exception was successful. In the case of DynamoDB, an `Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException` (or subclass) will be thrown if there was an error. Also, in the case of DynamoDB, the service will not respond until your item has been written to at least 2 locations, ensuring the integrity of your data.

Additionally, with the AWS SDK for PHP 2.x, you can use the long-form command syntax in order to have access to the Guzzle Request and Response objects, if you are interested in introspecting them. Here is an example:

```
$command = $client->getCommand('PutItem', array(/*...params...*/));
$model = $command->getResult(); // Actually executes the request

$request = $command->getRequest();
$response = $command->getResponse();
var_dump($response->isSuccessful());
```

Please also see the [Commands and Response Models sections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html#commands) of the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide.